# Statistics on which pages on my site users have Facebook-liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have Facebook "Like" buttons across my site and I'd like to see which articles get the most likes. I tried "[Insights for your Domain](http://www.facebook.com/insights/)", but I keep getting this error:

> The application ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your application to be a prefix of http://rapgenius.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go to http://www.facebook.com/developers, enter app settings, switch to "Web Site" tab and enter `rapgenius.com` into "Site Domain" field.

Comment: That worked; thanks! (Is there any way to access this data programmatically?)

Comment: @Horace: yes by using FQL on insights table: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights

Comment: @Horace also take a look at `application` and `metrics` tables, some stats are there as well.